# Filesaver and requireJS : Mismatched anonymous define

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I user [FilesaverJS](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) for save JSON file on the client side.

I've an error when i load Filesaver JS with RequireJS:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {
    return saveAs;
}
```

My requirejs optimizer config file :

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        ...
        blobjs                 : "../../libs/blobjs/Blob",
        ....
        filesaver              : "../../libs/filesaver/FileSaver",
    },
    shim : {
        ...
        blobjs: {
             exports: "Blob"
        },
        filesaver: {
             exports: "Filesaver"
        },
        ...
   },

   optimize: 'uglify2',
   uglify2: {
      output: { beautify: true },
      beautify: { semicolons: false }
   },
   baseUrl                 : '../assets/js/',
   mainConfigFile          : '../assets/js/config.js',
   name                    : 'formbuilder',
   out                     : 'formbuilder.min.js',
   output : { beautify: true },
   preserveLicenseComments : false,

   include : ['here i include some views template']
});
```

And in my code :

```
var blob = new Blob([jsonContent], {
     type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
});

saveAs(blob, collectionAndFilename['filename'] + '.json');
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. after an investigation I realized that I was loading the  FileSaver file in a script tag, and since inside the FileSaver the define() function is called - this was a problem.

This is what states in the [reauire.js docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch):

> Be sure to load all scripts that call define() via the RequireJS API.
>   Do not manually code script tags in HTML to load scripts that have
>   define() calls in them.

I loaded the file with the requireJS API and everything works just fine...

Comment: This answer would be a lot more helpful if you posted the code you used to get the  require call back function to load with filesaver . this answer tells me why the problem is happening but IMO requirejs docs are bad when it needs more recipes.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

```
requirejs(["lib/FileSaver"], function(){
    console.log("in FileSAver");

    var text = createString();
    var fileName = getFileName();

    var blob = new Blob([text], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    window.saveAs(blob, fileName);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `FileSaver.js` is using named AMD module, you have to use it as package in `require.config` file, juts like `moment` library.

```
require.config({
    packages: [{
      name: 'moment',
      location: './js/resources/',
      main: 'moment'
    }, {
      name: 'FileSaver.js',
      location: './js/resources/',// path where you have placed FileSaver.js file
      main: 'FileSaver.js'
    }]
  });
```

and then just require package `FileSaver.js`

```
  requirejs(["FileSaver.js"], function(FileSaver) {
    //FileSaver is now available as function
    console.log(FileSaver);
  });
```

Comment: This does not explain the error that the OP was getting. There is no "Mismatched anonymous define" error to which the solution *hinges* on setting `packages`. The accepted answer explains what the OP did wrong.

Comment: yeah , but if it helps anyone, loading file via requireJS API only is not a true solution because i tried that already. Notice incorrect usage of ```filesaver: {exports: "Filesaver"}, ``` does not work